# Done Button For PickerView ToolBar Not Working

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, uipickerview, toolbar

Done button added to pickerview toolbar,
But on click done button click event is not working.

```
    public override void ViewDidLoad(){
         myPickerView = new UIPickerView (RectangleF.Empty){
            AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth,
            ShowSelectionIndicator = true,
            Model = model,
            Hidden = true,
            BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear
        };

        toolbar = new UIToolbar();
        toolbar.BarStyle = UIBarStyle.Default;
        toolbar.Translucent = true;
        toolbar.SizeToFit();

// Create a 'done' button for the toolbar and add it to the toolbar
        UIBarButtonItem doneButton = new UIBarButtonItem("Done", UIBarButtonItemStyle.Done,
            (s, e) => {
                Console.WriteLine ("Calling Done!");
                txt_RegistrationType.Text = selectedType;
                txt_Email.ResignFirstResponder();
                txt_UserName.ResignFirstResponder();
                txt_Password.ResignFirstResponder();
                txt_PhoneNumber.ResignFirstResponder();
                txt_ConformPassword.ResignFirstResponder();
            });
        toolbar.SetItems(new UIBarButtonItem[]{doneButton}, true);
        model.PickerChanged += (sender, e) => {
            Console.WriteLine("selected vlaue {0}",e.SelectedValue);
            txt_RegistrationType.Text = e.SelectedValue;
        };

this.myPickerView.AddSubview (toolbar);
myPickerView.Frame = PickerFrameWithSize (myPickerView.SizeThatFits (SizeF.Empty));
View.AddSubview (myPickerView);
myPickerView.AddSubview (toolbar);
}
```

On click selected items

its shows pickerView "PickerView.Hidden = false" which appears picker view and toolbar with done button.  When click the done button on toolbar its click event is not working.

Please let me know for getting an event on click done button.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I want to point out that you're adding your "toolbar" to your current "UIPickerView" twice. Once with:

```
this.myPickerView.AddSubview (toolbar);
```

and another time with:

```
myPickerView.AddSubview (toolbar);
```

Secondly, why the toolbar? It only adds complexity and dependencies to your project.

What I suggest, is scrap the whole block of code, and make two separate controls on this view:

1. A button
2. A UIPickerView

   ```
   public override void ViewDidLoad()
   {
       UIButton button = new UIButton (new RectangleF (5, 5, frame_width, 30));
       button.TouchUpInside += Method;

       UIPickerView pickerView = new UIPickerView (new RectangleF (5, 45, frame_width, 180));
       pickerView.Model = model

       this.View.AddSubviews (new UIView[]{button, pickerView});
   }

   void Method (object sender, eventargs e)
   {
       Console.WriteLine ("Done");
       /*If you want to make the pickerView disappear, 
       you can add a pickerView.Hide() here, and then call a method 
       to redraw the controls on the current view.*/
   }
   ```

I hope this helps. Good luck!